# Proving that $G / N \cong (\Bbb R^\times, \cdot)$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G=(\Bbb C \backslash \{0\}, \cdot)$ and $N = \{a+bi \in \Bbb C : a^2 + b^2 = 1\}$. Prove that $N \lhd G$ and that $G / N \cong (\Bbb R^\times, \cdot)$.

I already proved $N \lhd G$, but I'm having problems proving the second assertion. I've been trying to find an isomorphism but I haven't found it, cause I don't know how to describe the elements of $G/N$. Is there an easier way to prove this?

Comment: Careful! You wrote $\Bbb R^+$, when you (probably) meant $\Bbb R^\times$.

Comment: No. I meant $\Bbb R^+$ (the set of nonnegative real numbers). I don't even know what $\Bbb R^\times$ means.

Comment: You mean $(0,+\infty)$. In group theoretic contexts, this is denoted by $\Bbb R^\times$. $\Bbb R^+$ usually denotes the real numbers under *addition* rather than multiplication.

Comment: Ok. With $(\Bbb R^+, \cdot)$ I meant the set $(0, \infty)$ with the opperation $\cdot$ which means multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\phi:G\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^\times,\cdot)$ as $z \mapsto |z|$ (this is a homomorphism and is surjective. why?). Since you know the identity element of $(\mathbb{R}^\times,\cdot)$ is $1$ so the $\ker \phi = N$. Kernel of a homomorphism is always normal subgroup - which proves the first. Then use the first isomorphism theorem to see the isomorphism $G/N\cong (\mathbb{R}^\times,\cdot)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some intuition on why this is true, and how it leads to constructing the isomorphism. Note that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is the punctured complex plane, and $N$ is the circle of radius $1$. By modding out $N$, we're essentially ignoring the difference between points that lie on the same circle - that is, points with the same radius should end up lying in the same coset. Since we can view the punctured plane as the union of a collection of circles of radius $r$ for every $0 < r < \infty$, it seems that we should send points on a circle to the radius; that is,

$$a + bi \mapsto \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = |a + bi|$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the (surjective) homomorphism $\eta:\Bbb C^\times \to \Bbb R^\times$ given by $z\mapsto |z|$. Then $|(a,b)|=1\iff a^2+b^2=1$. The elements of $G/N$ are cosets of complex numbers with equal modului, namely, circles of radius $r$ as $r$ ranges through all positive real numbers, for $a\sim b\iff ab^{-1}\in N\iff |ab^{-1}|=1\iff |a|=|b|$.